# CSS + Opacity change on Hover + Flickering

Tags: css, hover, opacity

I am trying to achieve a very simple thing: change opacity of a table row on hover.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work very good, because if I hover in and out very fast, sometimes the opacity change is too slow and it seems like the colors are flickering. This flickering doesn't happen when I hover in and out kinda slow.

I made an example so you know what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfhTW/2/

Is this behavior a browser bug or is something wrong with my code? And can it be fixed somehow? I have tried to use a Jquery script instead of doing the opacity change via CSS, but the results are the same :/

Comment: The problem appears to be Firefox specific. I have just updated my Chrome to the newest version and the flickering there is gone. However in Firefox 6.0.2 it is still there. I didnt even look at IE, since it has some problems with opacity anyways.

Comment: p.s. did you see the flickering too with Firefox 6.0.2 or is it probably just something with my configuration and I am the only one who sees the flickering?

Comment: I'm seeing same behaviour in Firefox 6.0.2.  It seems to be related to the default `display: table-cell` that a `<td>` has.  When I changed to `display: block`, the problem was gone, but of course the table layout was screwed up.  Since your opacity change is only changing colors, could you do it with a color change on `:hover` instead?

Comment: Hi Pat, Do you mean changing colors of text and background color to achieve almost the same result? I guess I could do that. Good idea! But it wont look identical as changing opacity, or? I will probably go with that anyways if i dont find another work around. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ha, it's almost the same problem the webkit sometimes have. So, I've tried to emulate the fix for webkit (the one with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)`), but using the 2D transform, and it worked!

So, it seems like just adding `-moz-transform: rotate(0);` to the elements that are affected by flickering solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/yfhTW/4/

Comment: Wow! It does really seem to work. You´re amazing! :) However I wonder, if some1 could explain me why this works, but nevertheless thanks very much!

Comment: Looks like modern browsers apply a slight different rendering/reflow rules to the blocks that are affected by CSS3 transforms. So, when something goes wrong it's just another thing to try. Just like `zoom:1` for IE :)

Comment: Good to know. I am gonna save that snippet, so I can try it when I have problems with some css3 effects again. I think I would have never been able to get the solution to this one myself - so thanks again :)

Comment: But be aware of unwanted behaviour relating to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10814448/5159481

Comment: Thank you! Didn't fix it for me this time, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134935/weird-css3-transition-flickering did

Answer (score 5):

Try to add the `border: 1px solid transparent;` to the element (not to `:hover` pseudoclass). It worked for me.

Comment: This works where you have an image with opacity e.g. the image contains a shadow effect

Answer (score 3):

For people coming here who have an image with an opacity that isn't 1, and have a similar flicker, make sure you set `background-color:white;` on the image!  I know this doesn't resolve the question at hand but it is a similar problem.

```
.post img { opacity:.8; background-color:white; }
.post:hover img { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This did not work for me and so I thought I would mention what did. I had to add overflow:hidden to all of the surrounding elements.

Answer (score 2):

In case the affected element is already translated (and thus, the [fix by kizu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623025/2607135) is not applicable) make sure to set `-webkit-backface-visiblity`:

```css
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: This fixed it for me! It's strange because I could only notice this issue on certain monitors.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the above suggestons, adding a z-index to the item the hover effect was being applied to solved the problem for me.

Comment: Could you post a forked fiddle or code block to improve your answer.