# Looping background images flash between image on first run

Tags: css, css-animations

I had an animation to loop through several background images...

```
@keyframes loop-background { 
    0% { background-image: url('1.jpg'); } 
    17% { background-image: url('2.jpg'); } 
    34% { background-image: url('3.jpg'); } 
    51% { background-image: url('4.jpg'); } 
    68% { background-image: url('5.jpg'); } 
    85% { background-image: url('6.jpg'); } 
    100% { background-image: url('7.jpg'); } 
}
```

On the first run through, there would be a brief flash between each image while they loaded. Then the flash would disappear. Why?

I've tried several fixes involving applying needless transforms to the element hosting the animation, including:

- [`position: static;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20297373/1524502)
- [`will-change: background-image;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)
- [`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020881/1524502)
- [`-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`](https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-stop-css-animation-flicker-in-webkit)
- `position: fixed;  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` together

So far, nothing's worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course! Because the images were taking a little time to load.

I added a hidden div in front of my main one that had each of the images set as a background as well.

```
<div id="dummy" hidden></div>
<style>
#dummy {
    display: none; 
    background-image: url("1.jpg";), url("2.jpg";), url("3.jpg";), url("4.jpg";), url("5.jpg";), url("6.jpg";);">
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but putting the first image as last seems to work nice !

```
0% { background-image: url('1.jpg'); }
```