# Fixed position not working in Safari 7

Tags: css, safari, safari7

I have a fixed position div that sits at the bottom of the screen as I scroll, not moving. However, on Safari, this div acts like it is absolutely positioned, and moves up and down with the rest of the content. When I click "Inspect Element", the programmed (desired) location is highlighted, not the visual (actual?) location.

I am unable to recreate this issue in a fiddle. This is not happening in Chrome, FF, or IE (10+).

Here's a screenshot of the difference between the visual (the character count box) and the programmed location (the highlighted area).

[image: Screenshot of phantom div]

There are more actual layers of css and html on top of these, but here's the immediate code:

**html** simplified

```
<article class="parent">
  <article class="inner-wrapper">
    <div id="counter">
      Character Count: <span class="tally">*javascript calculation*</span>
    </div>
  </article>
</article>
```

**scss**

```
article.parent {
  max-width: rem(640);
  margin: 0 auto rem(30) auto;
  padding: 0 rem(10);

 #counter {
   position: fixed;
   border: #888 solid 1px;
   bottom: 130px;
   left: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 10px;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
   font-size: .8em;
   min-width: 150px;
 }
```

}

How can I make this div behave in Safari, so that the visual sits on top of the programmed location?

Comment: can you share the html and css?

Comment: I can't, unfortunately. I know this is a long shot, but I thought I'd try.

Comment: no it will be very easy one i think > so you need a div always attached to top of the window whenever you scroll ---if i am not wrong??

Comment: Yes sir. And that's how this works on Chrome, FF and IE 10. Stand by, I can actually give you the immediate CSS.

Comment: please give the css i will try

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BUG FOUND:

I was able to trace the bug to a hardware-acceleration "trick" we were using by including these two rules in a parent element:

```
transform: translateZ(0)
perspective: 1000
```

By removing these two rules, the element now behaves as expected. More good information about this issue here: [CSS performance relative to translateZ(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814178/css-performance-relative-to-translatez0)

**Bonus Bug Fix:** Removing these rules in the HTML body caused various element-overlap problems in our PhantomJS/Poltergeist tests. Apparently PhantomJS doesn't move elements properly on its own. We included these rules only for the tests and currently everything is running fine.

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

I was able to fix this problem by pulling the counter from the parent container:

```
<article class="parent">
  <article class="inner-wrapper">
    ...
  </article>
  <div id="counter">
    Character Count: <span class="tally">*javascript calculation*</span>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sosypjLg/1/

```
#counter {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

you need this css style

Comment: This sticks to the top of the div. I'm looking to stick this to the bottom (or top, whichever) of the window.

Comment: Now this sticks to the bottom of the div. I'm looking for this stick to the bottom of the window, so that when I scroll the div up and down, this stays put.

Comment: i am confused just see this fiddle if this is you want

http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/

Comment: That fiddle does what I want it to do, but that code does not work in my project, unfortunately.

Comment: i have updated the answer, if it is not working for you send your code to me  i will fix it ok

Comment: Still not working. I can't send the code, as it's a private project, unfortunately. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: hmm.. without knowing your code i cant solve your problem, sorry mate