# If I use CSS scale on my page and then load another website containing animation into an iframe, my page gets blurry and animations misbehave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, iframe

I use a combination of jQuery and CSS to run animations. This works very well until I load a website into an iframe on the page.

If the loaded website contains animations, my animations stop working correctly. Also fine lines mostly disappear and my fonts start to look very blocky.

I'm at my wits end. I tried just using CSS animations, these didn't fix anything. I've tried to use other animation libraries (velocity), but nothing fixes the problem.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

**Edit 1**:
First, I'm sorry for not providing any code. The javascript "app" is very large and this problem only occurs when I load a website into an iframe that contains some animation.

I have tried the jQuery's "noConflict" mode (to no avail). I am going to build a small page with just one animation and an iframe to see if I can replicate the problem, I'll post the full code etc.

***Thanx for the replies so far.***

**Edit 2**:
I have some code that illustrates the problems to the pages look and feel but I don't have an example of an animation problem. Still, I think the code demonstrates the problem.

I now have some code. When you load the page, please try this:

1. Press the button labeled 'Open/Close the Menu': You should see a "menu" slide to the right, out from under the pale blue cover.
2. Press the button labeled 'Open/Close the Menu' again: The menu slides back to the left and is hidden.
3. Pay close attention to the text on the buttons when you press the button labeled 'Load/Unload website in iframe'. On my MacBook the text becomes noticeably blurry.
4. If you press the 'Load/Unload website in iframe' button a second time, the text goes back to looking sharp.
5. If you repeat these steps after using the button labeled 'Toggle scale from 1.2 to 1 and back' to set the scale to 1, there is no blurriness.

**N.B.**:
After completing my initial test page, I realized the blurriness occured even if no jQuery animate command was used (i.e.: I removed the toggleMenu routine).

After testing without animation, I tried testing without jQuery at all. Voila, the blurriness disappears.

***So***: Has anyone heard of this problem? I don't think I can rewrite the current 'app' without jQuery.

*Code: Test: jQuery and animation*

```
<html class="scaled">
  <head>
    <title>Test: jquery and animation</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      html {
        display                                            : none;
        -moz-transform-origin                              : 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin                               : 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin                                : 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin                           : 0 0;
        transform-origin                                   : 0 0;
      }

      body {
        font-family                                        : Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      #toggleMenu {
        box-shadow                                         : 5px 5px 12px rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.5);
        position                                           : relative;
        width                                              : 100px;
      }
      #toggleMenu div {
        border-bottom                                      : 1px solid #0276fd;
        width                                              : 100px;
      }

      #menuCover {
        box-shadow                                         : 0 5px 12px rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.5);
        background-color                                   : #0276fd;
        height                                             : 170px;
        position                                           : relative;
        top                                                : -170px;
        width                                              : 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var
          Set_Scale                                        = function(fScale) {
            jQuery('html').css({
              'display'                                    : 'block',
              '-moz-transform'                             : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              '-ms-transform'                              : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              '-o-transform'                               : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              '-webkit-transform'                          : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              'transform'                                  : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')'
            });
          }
        ;                                                                                          // End of vars

        Set_Scale(1.2);

        this.toggleMenu                                    = function() {
          var
            jqMenu                                         = jQuery('#toggleMenu')
          ;                                                                                        // End of vars

          if (true == jqMenu.hasClass('open')) {
            jqMenu
              .removeClass('open')
              .animate({
                'left'                                     : 0
              }, 250)
            ;
          } else {
            jqMenu
              .addClass('open')
              .animate({
                'left'                                     : '101px'
              }, 250)
            ;
          }
        };

        this.loadWebsite                                   = function() {
          var
            jqiframe                                       = jQuery('iframe')
          ;                                                                                        // End of vars

          if (true == jqiframe.hasClass('website')) {
            jqiframe
              .removeClass('website')
              .attr('src', '')
            ;
          } else {
            jqiframe
              .addClass('website')
              .attr('src', 'http://www.nbc.com')
            ;
          }
        };

        this.toggleScale                                   = function() {
          var
            jqHTML                                         = jQuery('html')
          ;                                                                                        // End of vars

          if (true == jqHTML.hasClass('scaled')) {
            jqHTML.removeClass('scaled');
            Set_Scale(1);
          } else {
            jqHTML.addClass('scaled');
            Set_Scale(1.2);
          }
        };

      });
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="toggleMenu()"  value="Open/Close the Menu">
    <input type="button" onclick="loadWebsite()" value="Load/Unload website in iframe">
    <input type="button" onclick="toggleScale()" value="Toggle scale from 1.2 to 1 and back">
    <br/><br/>

    <div id="toggleMenu">
      <div>Menu Item 1</div>
      <div>Menu Item 2</div>
      <div>Menu Item 3</div>
      <div>Menu Item 4</div>
      <div>Menu Item 5</div>
      <div>Menu Item 6</div>
      <div>Menu Item 7</div>
      <div>Menu Item 8</div>
      <div>Menu Item 9</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menuCover"></div>

    <iframe src="" frameborder=""></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Code: Test: jQuery but no animation*

```
<html class="scaled">
  <head>
    <title>Test: jquery but no animation</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      html {
        display                                            : none;
        -moz-transform-origin                              : 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin                               : 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin                                : 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin                           : 0 0;
        transform-origin                                   : 0 0;
      }

      body {
        font-family                                        : Arial, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var
          Set_Scale                                        = function(fScale) {
            jQuery('html').css({
              'display'                                    : 'block',
              '-moz-transform'                             : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              '-ms-transform'                              : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              '-o-transform'                               : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              '-webkit-transform'                          : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')',
              'transform'                                  : 'scale(' + fScale + ', ' + fScale + ')'
            });
          }
        ;                                                                                          // End of vars

        Set_Scale(1.2);

        this.loadWebsite                                   = function() {
          var
            jqiframe                                       = jQuery('iframe')
          ;                                                                                        // End of vars

          if (true == jqiframe.hasClass('website')) {
            jqiframe
              .removeClass('website')
              .attr('src', '')
            ;
          } else {
            jqiframe
              .addClass('website')
              .attr('src', 'http://www.nbc.com')
            ;
          }
        };

        this.toggleScale                                   = function() {
          var
            jqHTML                                         = jQuery('html')
          ;                                                                                        // End of vars

          if (true == jqHTML.hasClass('scaled')) {
            jqHTML.removeClass('scaled');
            Set_Scale(1);
          } else {
            jqHTML.addClass('scaled');
            Set_Scale(1.2);
          }
        };

      });
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="loadWebsite()" value="Load/Unload website in iframe">
    <input type="button" onclick="toggleScale()" value="Toggle scale from 1.2 to 1 and back">
    <br/><br/>

    <iframe src="" frameborder=""></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Code: Test: no jQuery and no animation*

```
<html id="elementHTML" class="scaled">
  <head>
    <title>Test: no jquery and no animation</title>

    <style>
      html {
        -moz-transform-origin                              : 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin                               : 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin                                : 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin                           : 0 0;
        transform-origin                                   : 0 0;

        -moz-transform                                     : scale(1, 1);
        -ms-transform                                      : scale(1, 1);
        -o-transform                                       : scale(1, 1);
        -webkit-transform                                  : scale(1, 1);
      }
      html.scaled {
        -moz-transform                                     : scale(1.2, 1.2);
        -ms-transform                                      : scale(1.2, 1.2);
        -o-transform                                       : scale(1.2, 1.2);
        -webkit-transform                                  : scale(1.2, 1.2);
      }

      body {
        font-family                                        : Arial, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      loadWebsite                                          = function() {
        if ('website' == document.getElementById('elementIFRAME').className) {
          document.getElementById('elementIFRAME').className = '';
          document.getElementById('elementIFRAME').src       = '';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('elementIFRAME').className = 'website';
          document.getElementById('elementIFRAME').src       = 'http://www.nbc.com';
        }
      };

      toggleScale                                          = function() {
        if ('scaled' == document.getElementById('elementHTML').className) {
          document.getElementById('elementHTML').className = '';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('elementHTML').className = 'scaled';
        }
      };
    </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="loadWebsite()" value="Load/Unload website in iframe">
    <input type="button" onclick="toggleScale()" value="Toggle scale from 1.2 to 1 and back">
    <br/><br/>

    <iframe id='elementIFRAME' src="" frameborder=""></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

TIA!
Bruce.

Comment: Please provide code so we can help by seeing what you have and we can work from there.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Derek S: The only errors in the console came from the site loaded in the iframe (some may have been caused by my loading it there).

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, you may want to check out jQuery's "noConflict" mode.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: How is it relevant to question? Iframe has its own document context

Comment: @A.Wolff I know that. It's more than possible to break that however. And if it were me, I'd tinker with noConflict because the symptoms sound like it might help. If you have a better answer, post it.

Comment: I don't have any better answer but for sure this isn't a jquery conflict as CSS animation are affected by mysterious symptom too. That's said, because OP didn't provide enough info, i don't think anyone would be able to help him

Comment: @Madbreaks: I have tried jQuery's "noConflict" mode without success.

Comment: @A.Wolff: I've now added three coding examples and some additional information. Unfortunately, my examples don't illustrate an animation problem, but the do show the "blurriness" issue.

Comment: @A.Wolff: Based on other things I've tried, I wonder if the iframed pages are using things like the translateZ(0) trick? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814178/css-performance-relative-to-translatez0