# Using transform: scale is not appropriately hiding a div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to hide a div with an animation on some action. My initial pass at it looked as follows:

```
.row {
  height: 50px;
  transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
  &.hidden {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

Where my DOM structure was as follows (with react):

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  <div className={styles.row} />
  <div className={classnames(styles.row, { [styles.hidden]: !this.state.active })}
</div>
```

While this did work, it was very slow. I have heard that transforms are efficient to transition in CSS, so I decided to try the following instead.

```
.row {
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;

  &.hidden {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

However, within the container, the second row is still *displaying* as a 50px box, but the inspector says that it has 0 height.

How can this transform be correctly applied to hide the second box?

Answer (score 1):

3D transforms are efficient because the browser will composite the targeted elements into their own layers and offload the animations to the GPU. `height` and even `scaleY()` are not 3D transformations and do not benefit from GPU acceleration (the CPU still handles it).

To go back to your example with `height`, you can force the browser to use GPU acceleration by tricking it with a fake transform property like `transform: translateZ(0);` (`translateZ()` is the 3D component of `translate3d()`, much like `scaleZ()` is the 3D component `of scale3d()`).

Here's a quick demo:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.row').classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateZ(0); /* or translate3d(0,0,0), rotateZ(360deg), etc. */
}

.row.hidden {
  height: 0;
}

button {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">Some text</div>

<button>Toggle Row Visibility</button>
```

With the added property, the browser should utilize GPU acceleration, significantly improving the animation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814178/css-performance-relative-to-translatez0) for more information related to transforms and GPU acceleration.

I would recommend trying this first to see if it speeds up the animation enough in your app. You could alternatively try adding the [`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) property though this is part of a working draft and currently non-standard.