# CSS Animation Residual Pixel Fragments

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've noticed residual pixel fragments left behind after a simple CSS animation of size and box shadows from one side of the screen to the other.

Here is the **[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjOJGZ)** so you can see it in action, and it looks like this in Chrome 66:

[image]

Is there anyway to remove these leftover fragments?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#container {
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
  
#box {
    
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: move 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  
  0% {
    
    left:  0;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    
    left: calc(100vw - 270px);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:
      0 0 0 20px black,
      0 0 0 40px cyan,
      0 0 0 60px yellow,
      0 0 0 80px pink,
      0 0 0 100px gray,
      0 0 0 120px blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no "fragment" for me on Firefox. Looks like a render issue from Chrome.

Comment: Can be seen on Chrome

Comment: May this is a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=691262#c69

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like a rendering bug that disappears when using `overflow: hidden;` on the `#box` element:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#box {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: move 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(100vw - 250px);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px black, 0 0 0 40px cyan, 0 0 0 60px yellow, 0 0 0 80px pink, 0 0 0 100px gray, 0 0 0 120px blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I have seen similar problems in chrome and most of them can be fixed by adding `transform:translateZ(0);` on the element. Adding `transform:translateZ(0);` does seem to work here. [More about translateZ(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814178/css-performance-relative-to-translatez0)

```css
* {
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#container {
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
  
#box {
    
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: move 2s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  transform:translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes move {
  
  0% {
    
    left:  0;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    
    left: calc(100vw - 250px);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:
      0 0 0 20px black,
      0 0 0 40px cyan,
      0 0 0 60px yellow,
      0 0 0 80px pink,
      0 0 0 100px gray,
      0 0 0 120px blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion.  Since this does work it's safe to assume that the rendering bug occurs only within the 2D space.  It also saved 5% of my CPU in Chrome by offsetting it to the GPU!

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 Great :)